# Importing files greater than 16 MB to MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

As a part of my project ,I want to import multiple JSON files that are greater than the size limit for mongoimport which is 16MB, to my MongoDB database.Is there a way I can do this ?(other than GridFS).

Comment: "it might make it difficult" - it __will__ make it impossible (not merely difficult) to query inner structure of the files (without fetching them).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so we can't query them using db.fs.chunks.find() command?

Comment: GridFS treats its files as binary blobs, so no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Documents in MongoDB can't exceed 16MB (default limit). Therefore, to import your big files so that they're queryable later, you'll have to generate multiple documents from them.

And also it's likely that you'll have to write a program that does this: read json file, split it according to your logic, call mongo db driver to insert small docs into the database.

If you don't need queryability, then just shove them to GridFS, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Search and download MongoDB Compass version 1.26.1 from Google. I encountered a similar issue with the latest version, 1.38.2, which has an import limit of 16MB. Despite trying numerous solutions, none of them worked until I remembered that two years ago, this older version of MongoDB Compass was able to successfully import large JSON files. With this version, I just successfully imported a 51MB json file.